# How to UPDATE all columns in a Table from FLAT FILE Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

My DB Table does not Update columns from an OLE DB Destination, I need to UPDATE all columns in an OLE DB Destination table that I get from a FLAT FILE Source (.csv).

The .csv file data inside changes everyday, so when i execute the DATA FLOW, the FLAT FILE Source updates fine, but the data in the OLE DB Destination does not update, so the DB Table never updates data.

Should I configure an OLE DB Command ?

So this is what I have and how I have set it up.

1. I'm using SQL Server 2012 STD
2. I have a SSIS Project in Visual Studio.
3. DATA FLOW has been set up.
4. Inside DATA FLOW I have FLAT FILE Source that connects to an OLE DB Destination. (works fine)
5. All connection managers setup and working fine.
6. Tables has been created in Management Studio already.

If i need to use an OLE DB Command, should it be something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET column1=?, column2=?, column3=?
WHERE column1=?, column2=?, column3=?
```

Here is my actual query i need to use, will this work ?

````
set 
candidateName=?, 
candidateFirstname=?,
candidateLogin=?,
candidateEmail=?, 
candidateRefNumber=?, 
candidateGuid=?,
candidateEntityName=?, 
'M-Sure Client Engagement Specialist'=?,
'Area Sales Manager'=?, 
Region=?, 
'Group Name'=?, 
'FSB License Holder'=?,
'Agent Name'=?, 
trainingId=?,
trainingTitle=?,
trainingGuid=?, 
sessionId=?,
sessionTitle=?,
sessionGuid=?,
sessionStartDate=?, 
sessionEndDate=?,
contentGuid=?, 
contentRefNumber=?,
contentTitle=?,
firstLaunchDate=?,
completionTime=?, 
score=?, 
timeGlobal=?, 
progression=?, 
status=?

WHERE

candidateName=?, 
candidateFirstname=?,
candidateLogin=?,
candidateEmail=?, 
candidateRefNumber=?, 
candidateGuid=?,
candidateEntityName=?, 
'M-Sure Client Engagement Specialist'=?,
'Area Sales Manager'=?, 
Region=?, 
'Group Name'=?, 
'FSB License Holder'=?,
'Agent Name'=?, 
trainingId=?,
trainingTitle=?,
trainingGuid=?, 
sessionId=?,
sessionTitle=?,
sessionGuid=?,
sessionStartDate=?, 
sessionEndDate=?,
contentGuid=?, 
contentRefNumber=?,
contentTitle=?,
firstLaunchDate=?,
completionTime=?, 
score=?, 
timeGlobal=?, 
progression=?, 
status=?```
````

Comment: Have you tried to output the final OLE DB Command to see what is actually being ran?  Are you sure the record values in the table match the record values in the csv?  Can you give an example of one that doesn't update?  CSVs can be tricky due to extra spaces, extra commas causing an early column break, etc.

Comment: Hi @TTeeple, no i haven't yet tried the query i mentioned, i will execute and let you know.

Comment: check your where syntax. TSQL uses AND/OR to link criteria.

Comment: Also you can refer to the following article for a step-by-step guide: [Update Data Using OLEDB Command Transformation in SSIS](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/update-data-using-oledb-command-transformation-in-ssis/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, in order to UPDATE existing rows in a table, you have to use an OLEDB Command, not an OLEDB Destination, and yes, the way you propose to do it is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I have not yet execute the query, will let you know what the outcome is...just one more question: if this works, and I configure a job schedule to run the SSIS package every day, will this now automatically update as it runs ?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this second question.   If it runs every day, the OLEDB command will be executed every day, of course.   It seems obvious, so I'm probably misunderstanding something about what you're asking.